# Manually creating Security Key gives PHP error

Tags: craft3, install, security

I'm going on 5 days of banging my head on my desk here.

I'm simply not getting how to install it on my production server. I have Craft working beautifully locally...but getting it to my server is a whole other matter.

So I have ssh'd into my VPS, then run 'wget 'https://craftcms.com/latest-v3.zip'' and unzipped it to try and get it running as just a barebones install. So now I'm going through the install instructions, and am running into an error when running the './craft setup/security-key' step:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'Phar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

Craft requires PHP 7.0 or later.

I created a phpinfo file and it's returning PHP Version 7.0.30.

Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well then. Apparently my shell user was using a different version of php than my domain. I was still at 5.6 on my shell user. I was all sorts of confused because I had a phpinfo.php file setup at my domain showing PHP 7.0, and in the web hosting domain panel, I had 7.0 chosen. Finally wrote to support and they sent directions on how to change it. Once I updated that, the security key was created just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try `php craft setup/security-key`?

Comment: Same response - still says I need php 7.0 or greater. Thanks for replying though!